# Will default gcc version change in 20.04

Tags: compiling, gcc, versions

I'm writing a book that discusses the assembly language generated by gcc. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. The default version of gcc is 9.3.0. The latest version of gcc in the repositories is 10.2.0. It's an introductory book, so I want everything to be as "standard" as possible for the reader. They've got enough to deal with in the book's material without having to deal with bleeding edge OS and compiler issues. Will gcc 9.3.0 remain the default during the remaining 4 years of 20.04's lifetime?

Comment: Yes, gcc will stay on 9.3.